# Verilog, Module Instantiation with inputs from different modules

Tags: module, verilog, instantiation, xilinx-ise

Module's Hierarchy where uart_receiver.v=ModuleA, RSD.v=ModuleB, uart_transmitter.V=ModuleC
[image]

Suppose I want to Instantiate **ModuleA** with inputs from different modules, B, and the name of inputs are: *WR_EN* from **moduleB** and *RD_EN*, *DT* from **moduleC**

```
module A(
  input wr_EN,
  input rd_EN,
  input DT,
  output out
);
```

I tried to do the below with no success, in ISE Xilinx with Verilog

**B MODULE**

```
module B(...)
  assign wr_EN = 1;
  ...  
  // Now call module A from B:
  module A A_instance(.wr_EN(wr_EN) );
```

**C MODULE**

```
module C(...) 
  ... 
  assign rd_EN = 0;
  assign DT = 1;
  .... 
  // And then call module A from C
  module A A_instance(.rd_EN(rd_EN), .DT(DT) );
```

If I call module instances with same names the program doesn't make a second instance, despite the fact that I want one. 
 I searched but I haven't found similar example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to clean up your question but I'm still not sure you intend to have two instances of **A** (one in **B** the other in **C**) or if your are trying to share one instance of **A** between **B** and **C**.

An instance represents a physical piece of hardware. The same instance cannot be shared between other module instances. You can route nets to connect instances. For example:

```
module TOP(...);
  ...
  A A_instance( .wr_EN(wr_EN), .rd_EN(rd_EN), .DT(DT), .out(out) );
  B B_instance( .wr_EN(wr_EN), ... );
  C C_instance( .rd_EN(rd_EN), .DT(DT), ... );
endmodule
```

You can place **A** inside of **B** or **C** and route the input from the other through a parent level.

```
module B(
  input rd_EN, // output for C connected at top
  input DT,    // output for C connected at top
  ...
);
  ...
  assign wr_EN = 1;
  A A_instance( .wr_EN(wr_EN), .rd_EN(rd_EN), .DT(DT), .out(out) );
endmodule
```

*or*

```
module C(
  input wr_EN, // output for B connected at top
  ...
); 
  ...
  assign rd_EN = 0;
  assign DT = 1;
  A A_instance( .wr_EN(wr_EN), .rd_EN(rd_EN), .DT(DT), .out(out) );
endmodule
```

If you placed an instance of **A** in **B** and **C**, then you have two independent instances, even if the input are from a common source.

Comment: Xmm thanks, the 1st sounds good. I have considered the 2nd or 3rd as a first thought. So, calling a module's instance 2 times with SAME name creates 2 different pieces of Hardware?

Comment: There would be two _instances_, and they are required to have different instance names. Verilog does not _call_ modules